# How to retrieve date from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to retrieve date as per input from user.The date is inserted in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`(**Stored as string**) in mongodb.  I want to know how to retrieve the record for the date the user has specified.

I have tried breaking down the date into year,month and day and then tried searching but still cannot find a solution. In the below find() code if I am searching it is returning both the records but I need only the record with date **"2019/11/12"**.

**user.db**

```
{
.
.
start_Date: "2019/11/12"
}

{
.
.
start_Date: "2019/12/12"
}
```

**app.js**

```
dbo
  .collection("testing")
  .find({ start_Date: { $regex: req.params.day, $options: "i" } })
  .toArray(function(err, n_date) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      console.log(n_date);
      resolve(n_date);
    }
  });
```

Not getting any error message.

Comment: its not clear to me why you're using a regex, and what is `req.params.day`?

Comment: You can use $dateToString operator from mongoDB and find your required entities, but for that you have to use aggregation.
See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get data from client side equal to sting of date save it

```
  var dateCommingFromClient = req.params.completeDate 
  // completeDate is like this "2019/11/12" not day only
  var query = { start_Date: dateCommingFromClient };
  dbo.collection("testing").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
```